# (click)="foo()" is not working in data table

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is my following code of datatable

```
datatable [options]="{
   colReorder: true,
   ajax: 'assets/api/tables/admin-list.json',
   columns: [ 
      {data: 'id'},
      {data: 'name'}, 
      {data: 'username'}, 
      {data: 'adminRole'},
      {data: 'siteId'},
      {defaultContent: '<button **(click)=\'foo()\'**>Edit</button>'},
      {defaultContent: '<button>Delete</button>'} 
  ]}"
  paginationLength="true" 
  tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" 
  width="100%">
```

In this code, angular click event is not bind

I am stuck in this part
Any solution ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because angular cannot bound to `click` because the code is being generated on the fly and Angular's compiler doesn't compile it as a Angular component , it would become normal html (string).

Your best solution would be to use `<button onCLick="foo()">` in a normal javascript way.

Or you could assign a class to them and then use `addEventListener` to those classes.

```
 <button class="myButtons">
```

Inside your component class :

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

   document.getElementsBytClassName('myButtons').addEventListener('click',foo)
}
```

Otherwise you must go in the direction of using `viewContainer` and loading the buttons as a template dynamically and that can be really painful.